# XSLT 2.0 - How to format text with numbers to numbers?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to transform
"**0 year(s), 0 month(s), 0 day(s)**" to "**000000**". In YYMMDD format.

I tried this but not sure how to format it to bring as YYMMDD if they are of single digit.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(substring-before(ns:Service,'year')),normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(ns:Service,'month'),',')),normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(ns:Service,'day'),'month(s),')))"/>
```

So, 1 year(s), 4 month(s), 23 day(s) transforming to 1423 but expected value is 010423.

14 year(s), 12 month(s), 11 day(s) transforming to 141211 correctly.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I would use analyze-string to extract the components:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="numbers" as="xs:integer*">
                <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+) year\(s\), ([0-9]+) month\(s\), ([0-9]+) day\(s\)">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:sequence select="xs:integer(regex-group(1)), xs:integer(regex-group(2)), xs:integer(regex-group(3))"/>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="for $n in $numbers return format-number($n, '00')" separator=""/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Transforms

```
<body>
  <data>1 year(s), 4 month(s), 23 day(s)</data>
  <data>14 year(s), 12 month(s), 11 day(s)</data>
</body>
```

into

```
<body>
  <data>010423</data>
  <data>141211</data>
</body>
```

With XSLT 3.0 as supported by Saxon 9.8 (including the open source HE edition) you could shorten it to

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="analyze-string(., '([0-9]+) year\(s\), ([0-9]+) month\(s\), ([0-9]+) day\(s\)')//*:group/format-number(xs:integer(.), '00')" separator=""/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

by using the `analyze-string` function instead of the `xsl:analyze-string` element.

Comment: Thank you, will try this out. How about if we need to get date difference in YYMMDD format. Date is 2016-07-27-07:00. How to get the value as 001019. Should I post this question in a separate thread?

Comment: You will need to ask a new question, but start by reading a documentation of XPath/XSLT functions, like http://maxtoroq.github.io/xpath-ref/ or like https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/, to see whether you can't figure it out using existing functions and operators working on date or dateTime or duration values.